# I'm trying to create my first web form app using c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create my first web form app and trying to use the checkbox is giving me issues. i want the submit button to deduct from my database and ive already done the checkbox

```
     private void BindGrid()
     {

         try
         {
             SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=W-IT004\\MSSQLSERVER2012;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=sa;Password=qwerty;Pooling=False");
             con.Open();
             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select [Title], [Duration], [OldBorrowPrice] ,[Damage Price] from Movie", con);
             SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
             DataTable dt = new DataTable();

             da.Fill(dt);

             GridView1.DataSource = dt;
             GridView1.DataBind();

             con.Close();
             da.Dispose();
         }
         catch (Exception ex )
         {

             string exx = ex.Message;
         }

    }
    protected void BorrowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: your question is unclear ..please provide more infos

Answer (score 1):

Here you have `DataTable dt=new DataTable();`

Try to use

```
DataSet ds=new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
GridView1.DataSource=ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

I hope it will work